# Multiple Wordpress websites on MAMP

Tags: wordpress, mamp

have a quite simple question here. I have installed MAMP and have folder on my desktop called MAMP which is set as a root. Inside are two installations of Wordpress, site1 and site2.
Site1 already has database and site itself is completely designed. I wanted to start second site so I added wordpress installation files to site2 folder.
If I now want to access site1 or start new installation for site2, I go to my browser and write localhost:8888. Here I will get choice to enter site1 or site2. If I click site2, as expected, I have Wordpress menu and I can start new installation. On the other hand if I click on site1, it takes me to my originally built website which now looks really bad(95% of design is missing, everything is messed up and I get 404 error). If I change root, and instead of MAMP i choose MAMP/site1 , then I can access directly localhost:8888 and I will see my site1 with its full design and functionality. So just a simple thing, changing the root directory for MAMP will make my site1 lose all its functionality. Where is the problem? I have following instructions from a youtube tutorial and I can see it is perfectly possible to run two sites simultaneously on MAMP.
This is what I am trying to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25ole-BzQcA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MAMP to install multiple websites. You must have previously installed Wordpress in directory 'site1' before you tried to install multiple sites.

Here is how to correct this -

1. Login to MAMP phpmyadmin page and go to Database for site1.
2. Look for table 'wp_options' or _options
3. Look for option_name 'siteurl' and 'home' - this for your setup will be 'localhost:8888'
4. Change siteurl and home to 'localhost:8888/site1'

Try to hit website http://localhost:8000/site1 and this should fix the problem.

Comment: This does work although it won't load all the photos. It does load the site and formatting, but some photos are missing and I get just blank white space instead of image.

Comment: In your browser view source - and see image URL - Are the image URL still pointing to old site URL? If yes, you need to rebuild permalink and that should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much a solution as it is a recommendation, if you plan to develop multiple sites over time and are primarily using Wordpress, I'd suggest you use this tool: https://localwp.com/

Much simpler to manage your sites, databases, and to switch between which sites you are working on at any given time from one interface.  Massive time saver.

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the above link or company, simply a satisfied user.

Comment: So LocalWP would replace MAMP  in that case. Can I import my website from MAMP to LocalWP?

Comment: Yes it would replace it.  It will do all the work for you, you can basically create any local WP site in a click or two including DB.  Yes you can import any WP site.  https://localwp.com/help-docs/getting-started/how-to-import-a-wordpress-site-into-local/